# PyQT Qrunnable memory usage, multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

1. Does somebody know how to minimize memory usage of QRunnable ? What are the pitfalls in using QRunnable and QThreadPool. I have simple application crawling urls and memory usage is astonishing. It looks like QRunnable objects aren't deleted after execution.
2. Is there any **rational way** for doing multithreading in PyQT where you have list of urls to crawl and you want to crawl for example 10 urls at once using threads ? I know how to do it in threading (producer/consumer) but threading doesn't work. QRunnable is so much buggy!

Comment: Is this question still relevant now that you have an answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971832/python-pyqt-pyside-qthread-limiting?

Comment: I must test this for a while to find out if this is the best solution but i can tell that this is better than QRunnable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any rational way for doing multithreading in PyQT where you
>   have list of urls to crawl and you want to crawl for example 10 urls
>   at once using threads ?

You can use 10 instances of [QWebView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebview.html) in single thread for example. QT is asynchronous and all instances will do there tasks parallelly. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12872076/1113207). Note, that each QWebView instance eat some memory. If you don't need javascript, just plain HTTP requests, you can use [QTextBrowser](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextbrowser.html) same way.